# Load array of images with Javascript & Webpack?

Tags: javascript, image, performance, webpack, lazy-loading

Hi friendly helpers of the internet,

I'm having trouble with images loading performances on a website I'm coding. I'm only using vanilla Javascript & Webpack.

The idea is simple, I'm loading an 4 arrays of 50-100 images, each array is 5Mo.
Theses images are changing on scroll to create an animation feeling (such as apple airpods pro website -> [apple.com/airpods-pro](https://www.apple.com/airpods-pro/))

So here is how I load theses images :

```
let homeImages = []
let aboutImages = []
let teamImages = []
let clientsImages = []

function importAll(r, array) {
    array.push(r.keys().map(r))
}

function createImagesArrays() {
    importAll(require.context('../assets/images/home/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/), homeImages)
    importAll(require.context('../assets/images/about/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/), aboutImages)
    importAll(require.context('../assets/images/team/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/), teamImages)
    importAll(require.context('../assets/images/clients/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/), clientsImages)
}
```

Once they are loaded, I simply pick them as the scroll counter is increasing and I set the source of my static fixed background to the current index.

The effect is working great on local environment, but when it comes to 3G-edge connection (yes we still have some users forced to use edge in France), the images are not loading fast enough.

Is there a smart way to load them before the user is entering the website ? Because I'm not using them directly in html, I don't know how to "lazy-load" them.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: i can't help you more .. but i can give some glimpse of snippet then you work and playaround with that

Comment: is that okay? then let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I figured out that I was only stacking paths in my array, so the correct import function was :

```
    importAll(r, array) {
        const allImages = r.keys().map(r)

        allImages.forEach(src => {
            const image = new Image()

            image.src = src

            array.push(image)
        })
    }
```

That way, the browser is loading correctly each images.